# How to loop or access Object Collection in ASP Classic (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

So I found this old web application (asp classic) in my workplace and been asked to modified it. What i'm trying to do is, I want to display all files from this particular folder. Instead of hardcoding each of the file name with its link, I tried as below:

```
<%
    var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fo = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var f = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var theFile = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    fo=fs.GetFolder("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\edocument\\MyFiles");
    f = fo.Files;

    For Each theFile in f
        Response.write(theFile.Name+"<br>");
    Next
%>
```

seems like `For Each` loop won't work/not recognized in `asp javascript` but  found some working example using `vbscript`. I also tried to access the collection directly:

```
 Response.write(f[0].Name);
```

but it says `...is null or not an object`

Any idea how can I access this Files Collection?

Comment: See: [Use JScript or JavaScript to traverse through a collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/visualstudio/general/use-jscript-javascript-traverse-collection).

Comment: @flakes wow thank you! solved my problem perfectly. been searching for it for a few days. You may post it as an answer

Comment: Glad to help. Please post your solution as an answer, you can mark it as an answer. It is allowed and encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript you need an `Enumerator()` [to walk the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284047/jscript-array-with-request-form), and either use `for next`, or `while` like in the example below

```
<% @LANGUAGE="JScript" %>
<%
var fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fo = fso.GetFolder("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\edocument\\MyFiles");

var f = new Enumerator(fo.Files);
f.moveFirst()
while (!f.atEnd()) {
   Response.Write(f.item().name + "<BR>");
   f.moveNext();
}

fo = null;
f = null;
fso = null;
%>
```